# Facebook SDK array profile

Tags: php, facebook, mysqli

I hope you can help, I am trying out new projects and would like the user to login using facebook. I have got it working and created a function which pulls the $profile array from the SDK and inserts it into my database if no email exists. Problem is, it always adds the user regardless and I have tried so many things to get it to work.

custom query function is the mysqli_query();

**Function called in facebook sdk:**

```
facebookLoginRegister($profile['name'], $profile['email'], $profile['email']);
```

**My Php is below:**

```
function facebookLoginRegister($name, $email, $username){ // start of facebook check

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" .$email. "'";
    $result = query($sql);

    if(count($result) === 1){ // does email exist in database #1
        if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])){ // if cookie is set then #2
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" .$_COOKIE['email']. "'"; 
            // find the row of info containing credentials
            $result = query($sql); // query the sql

            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $name;
        } // if cookie is set #2

        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $name;
        setcookie('email', $email, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    } // email exist in database #1

    if(!$result){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, username)";
        $sql .= " VALUES('" . $username . "', '" . $email . "', '".$name."');";

        $query_new_user_insert = query($sql); // this will either be True or false
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $name;
    }  
}
```

Comment: $result will always true even if the query return zero row.

Comment: There are a few inconsistencies in your `query` calls: `query($connection, $sql)` and `query($sql)`. Which one is the right one? Also, what does it return? a resource? an array?

Comment: query($sql) - this is a helper function I created. mysqli_query, I thought the query would result in a boolean. could be wrong though!

Comment: PHP.net: `mysqli_query `: Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: Alex Tartan you where right! the query function I made had $connection in there, this made the whole function break it seems. I removed it and its not adding every time the user logs in! Thank you for spotting it

Comment: This is hardly a Facebook-specific question (tags removed) – you have just a general, run-of-the-mill problem with your database queries and/or script logic.

Comment: Share code for `query()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
$result
```

is always true ! try something

```
if(count($result) > 0)
{
/* your code for if true*/
}
else
{
/* code for false*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the your doesn't allows the share their profile, you can not get the email address. From your query, you have verified the email id after that only queries process. So write the code if email not get

if(count($result) <=0 ){
}

Comment: I pull the email allready and add it to the database, the problem is that it will keep adding even if the email exists in the database. the above code didn't work for me

Comment: So the problem is result returning always true, so that the problem happening, change the if condition with $row_count = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" .$email. "'";
    $result = query($sql);
    if($result!="") $row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: if($row_count>0){  enter code if email exits} else { insert }